# Values from one sheet should be displayed in different sheet in same excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have one single excel file with three sheets in it. Namely: "Requisition form" , "Call order Form" and "Summary Sheet". I would like to copy all the values which are greater than 0 in "Column F" and Column I in "Summary Sheet" and paste it in sheet "Call order Form" in column starting F16 and G16. Below is the VBA code which I have written. But I dont know why it is not getting executed. I am getting error in it. Please help me in correcting the code.

Call Order Form:
[image]

Summary Sheet:
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Call Order Form").Range("A16:G29").ClearContents
 Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Summary Sheet")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Call Order Form")
    Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If rDest.Row < 15 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("F16")

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With wsData.Range("F7:H" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 6 Then GoTo CleanExit     'No data
        .AutoFilter 1, ">0", xlFilterValues 'Filter on column F for values >0
        Intersect(.Worksheet.Range("F:F,I:I"), .Offset(1)).Copy 'Copy filtered values in columns F and I only
        rDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    'Paste values only to destination
        .AutoFilter 'Clear filter
    End With

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What error and on which line?

Comment: Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Call Order Form") Not getting executed from this line and gives me error Run time error 9 script out of range.

Comment: No such sheet . Please add those details to your question.

Comment: I tend to agree with SJR, I created the sheets and copied your vba sub. Its not working perfectly but no errors. Check your sheet names

Comment: I have checked the sheet names and there are three sheets in my excel file and the name also I copied it as is. I dont know why it is showing me error?

Comment: I've just told you! The sheets need to be in the active workbook which is probably not what you think it is. Check for trailing or leading spaces in the sheet names too.

Comment: @SJR : I did check the sheets are in active workbook and also did check the spaces. Everything looks fine to be but still gives me same error which is strange.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use Advanced Filter to populate your column. Then you can record a macro to update the filter.